Dependency not found while trying to run Torch in Jupyter Notebook
I have a AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics(1.80 GHz) unit and Windows 11.
I am trying to run the following code in the Jupyter Notebook
import os
import gymnasium as gym 
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy

However I am met with the following error
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\chint\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I found out that the above error is because I don't have a NVIDIA GPU and Cuda within Torch is causing the above error
So I went through the solution mentioned here
Cannot import Pytorch [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
and I reinstalled Torch using the following code
pip install torch==2.3.0+cpu torchvision==0.18.0+cpu torchaudio==2.3.0+cpu --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

Basically trying to just get the CPU version. However I am still getting the original error. Any idea on how to proceed?

Does this answer your question? PyTorch Error loading "\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies

on pytorch.org you can select system, LibTorch and CPU and download zip file - maybe it will have all needed libraries. You may also use python -m pip install ... to make sure you don't install it with some other Python.
